# Issues with for circle - wrong result

Tags: php, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
$pages=10;
$pages_list='';
if($pages>1){
   for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++){
     $pages_list.='<label class="am-pages> [ '.$i.' ] </label>&nbsp;';
   }
}
```

The result is as follows:
[ 2 ]   [ 4 ]   [ 6 ]   [ 8 ]   [ 10 ]

Expected to be:
[ 1 ]   [ 2 ]   [ 3 ]   [ 4 ]   [ 5 ]

Please tell me, where did I go wrong?

Comment: Working fine:  https://3v4l.org/jMHKN. seems like the issue is either coming from somewhere else or full code is not provided by you. Please provide the full code

Comment: There must be more code, because this looks ok.

Comment: Your output is not possible with provided code. Maybe you have `$i += 2` or `$i++` somewhere else?

Comment: NickSp76 since you found answer as well as it's a simple TYPO mistake, so kindly delete your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you missed `"` `class="am-pages>` here. Add `"` after `class="am-pages">` will work

```
$pages=10;
$pages_list='';
if($pages>1){
   for($i = 1; $i<=$pages; $i++){
     $pages_list.='<label class="am-pages"> [ '.$i.' ] </label>&nbsp;';
   }
}
```

Comment: Typo mistakes should be commented on or closed not answered, as well as the issue faced by OP has no relation to it as per my knowledge. I am only giving suggestion.

Comment: Typo mistakes are a common occurrence, and I agree these questions should be closed, however, this answer does actually point out what the issue faced by the OP is.